# how to print a certain line in a file when user inputs a number

Tags: c, string, file

How do you print portions of a line in a file when a user enters a number.I want it to look through the file and find the same number and then print the rest of the line that the number is on

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about C, but you can do this extremely easily from the command line with grep.

`$ grep "Find this" filename.txt`

This command will print out all lines in the file that contain the string in quotes.

If you can enter system commands through C, you could use this method.

Comment: Not that I know of. I know very little C. Sorry this didn't work for you.